# Can't create JSON file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: json, visual-studio

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on JSONs and I follow the instruction:
File > New > File...

and I search for the file type "JSON" which is not there.

Could someone tell me what I need to install please :

[image]

Comment: You could also just create a text file and name it file.json instead of file.txt. There is no magic involved. It's just text.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install any VS extension.

You can add the file like above or simply right click on the folder you want the file in. `Add -> New Item`. The file type doesn't really matter.

[image]

From there, type your file name and add the `.json` file extension. Visual Studio will recognize the extension and know that it is of type JSON.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is probably very late to give in an answer, but I too faced an issue with creating and opening JSON files in Visual Studio 2019. So I found out this workaround after some tinkering.

So first, open up Visual Studio Installer, Tools > Get Tools and Features

[image: Open Visual Studio Installer]

Then in the window that has just opened, select Desktop Development with C++

[image: Desktop Development with C++]

Then, from the right panel uncheck all the Optional downloads, especially the "MSVC v142..."

[image: Uncheck optional downloads]

After doing this you would get JSON editor under Individual components

[image: JSON editor]

Click Modify.

I hope this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Installer

Install: .NET Core cross-platform development

Comment: Hi, did you find any documentation for this or just trial and error?

Comment: Trial and error, I saw that this workload is tied to JSONs so I figured there must be some components I might be missing contained in it. It's the only thing I did and worked immediately.